# Android studio + gradle : autocomplete for generated java files

Tags: android-studio, gradle, autocomplete, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android Studio project and the Gradle script generates some Java source files on the fly.

I wish to know if there is a way to allow the editor's autocomplete to works with theses generated files?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, add the directory where you generate to as a source directory for generated sources.

Comment: Thanks, but this folder (parents folder) is deleted at each build ! It is generated by a cmake file !

Once it is generated, the folders appears in Android Studio, but it seems the folder is not recognized as a java source folder !

Comment: As I said, while AS sees it, declare it as generated sources folder (right click, mark directory as, ...). AS will remember this setting even if the folder gets deleted and recreated.